# COUNT total DISTINCT values from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, distinct

I have table with 4 columns (ID, Code, title/name of disease and value) I just want total count of unique ID_patients with disease "A" or "B" (If patient had both diagnosis A and B, in resulting number will be counted only once).

I tried simple COUNT with GROUP BY, but after execute i get just new column with values.

Tried also subquery with (select, count, ...) but not worked too.
Thank you for advice and help.

Image here:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqwm5.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question easier to follow.  For instance, you don't list `id_patient` as a column in the table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be a `count(distinct)` with filtering:

```
select count(distinct id_patient)
from t
where disease in ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: still not working, i just need count of all id_patients

Comment: the above result will give the required result. You are combining the above query with other columns which doesn't really make sense. you are not explaining your requirement clearly

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar No, it won't because it will count the patients where a patient has only disease A only, but not disease B.

Comment: @Pred  I don't follow you. There is an [IN Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) .

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar And that IN will be evaluated for each row. It will match with all of the below pairs: `Patient1-DiseaseA`, `Patient2-DiseaseB`, `Patient3-DiseaseA`, `Patient3-DiseaseB`. The OP wants to count the patients which have both DiseaseA and DiseaseB.
The query with my example records will result in 3, while the expected result is 1 (Only Patient3 has both diseases). If I misiterpreted the question, than sorry, you are right

Comment: and there is a Distinct keyword applied to remove the duplicate count. The result will still be 3 and not 4

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar you are right, sorry, my bad!